# Existe alguma classe em c#(WPF) equivalente ao QSignalMapper do Qt?

Tags: c#, wpf

Quando estava a aprender C++/Qt utilizei uma classe muito interessante que me permitia associar vários botões da interface a um único evento que, mediante um valor pelo qual cada botão era mapeado, me permitia selecionar a ação a executar.
Algo deste tipo:

```
...
buttonx[0] = ui->b1;
buttonx[1] = ui->b2;
buttonx[2] = ui->b3;
buttonx[3] = ui->b4;
buttonx[4] = ui->b5;
buttonx[5] = ui->b6;
buttonx[6] = ui->b7;
buttonx[7] = ui->b8;
buttonx[8] = ui->b9;

QSignalMapper *signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(botaopressionado(int)));

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    signalMapper->setMapping(buttonx[i], i + 1);
    connect(buttonx[i], SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
}
```

...
Desta forma o "event handler" recebia um valor inteiro que, de acordo com o mapeamento, me indicava o botão que tinha sido pressionado.

```
void MainWindow::botaopressionado(int m){
// O botão pressionado foi o correspondente ao valor de m
...
}
```

Usando C# e WPF, qual será a melhor maneira de obter este resultado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer algo parecido, seria aproveitar a propriedade `Tag`, segundo a MSDN:

> Tag = Obtém ou define um valor de objeto arbitrário que pode ser usado para armazenar informações personalizadas sobre este elemento.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

     var buttons = new List<Button>();
     buttons.Add(new Button { Tag = 1 });
     buttons.Add(new Button { Tag = 2 });
     buttons.Add(new Button { Tag = 3 });

     foreach (var button in buttons)
         button.Click += Button_Click;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var valor = ((Button)sender).Tag;
    }
}
```

Uma outra forma, que exige mais código, é implementar a Interface `ICommand` mas ai você parte para o padrão MVVM.

```
private ICommand meuComando;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var buttons = new List<Button>();
    buttons.Add(new Button { CommandParameter = 1, Command = meuComando });
    buttons.Add(new Button { CommandParameter = 2, Command = meuComando });
    buttons.Add(new Button { CommandParameter = 3, Command = meuComando });

}
```

[Sobre ICommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms752308(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ainda não me sinto com coragem para pegar no MVVM, mas está na minha lista de "coisas a fazer ...".

Comment: Mas a primeira abordagem ajuda?

Comment: Sim claro. Obrigado.